# Install k8s 1.26 with Kubespray skipping all Calico steps

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I am working on installing/upgrading k8s cluster to version 1.26 and I wonder if I can somehow skip all the steps which tests/installs/configures Calico. The reason - I want to use Tigera operator to manage calico and I want to skip the steps related to Calico. Is there any key/argument for Kubespray which can do this?

I want to run Kubespray so it will skip all the steps related to Calico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [this github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/8458), that recommends setting `kube_network_plugin: cni` and then use the tigera operator.

The [documentation](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/operations/operator-migration) has a section on *"Switch your Calico installation from manifest-based resources to an installation managed by the Calico operator."* so that might work.

Alternatively, the users in the [calico slack channel](https://slack.projectcalico.org/) might be able to help.

Comment: that's awesome, thanks for the tip! I will try this tomorrow